# Select the value from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make my drop down menu select the value and display it when I select the item let go of my mouse button? BUT NOT when I click the little arrow drop down button.

HTML:

```
<select name="menu" id="menu"></select>
```

JS:

```
$("#menu").click(function () {
    var currentSelection = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    populate(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);

});
```

Problem is is that when I click the down arrow from the selection menu, it thinks I have clicked/selected an item already, and it calls the populate() function right there. How can I change it to only call populate() after I select an item and left click it?

Comment: use onchange handler (as @Jason P's answer) and inside it, use `this.value`: `$("#menu").change(function () {populate(this.value);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$("#menu").change(function () {
    //code here
});
```

---

Better use [this Keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$("#menu").change(function () {
    var currentSelection = this.value;
    populate(this.value);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tushar

Answer (score 3):

Try [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead:

```
$("#menu").change(function () {
```

So the event only fires when the value changes.

You can simplify your inner code too:

```
populate(this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You need to use `change` handler instead of `click` handler

```
$("#menu").change(function () {
    populate($(this).val());
});
```